# Calculate the LCM of two or three numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, math

I am using the following code to determine the **Greatest Common Denominator (GCD)** of two or three numbers:

```js
Math.GCD = function(numbers) {
  for (var i = 1 ; i < numbers.length ; i++){
    if (numbers[i] || numbers[i] === 0)
      numbers[0] = twogcd(numbers[0], numbers[i]);
  }
  return numbers[0];

  function twogcd(first, second) {
    if (first < 0) first = -first;
    if (second < 0) second = -second;
    if (second > first) {var temp = first; first = second; second = temp;}
    while (true) {
        first %= second;
        if (first == 0) return second;
        second %= first;
        if (second == 0) return first;
    }
   }
};

Math.LCM = function(first,second) {
    return first * (second / this.GCD(first, second)); // CANNOT FIGURE OUT HOW TO EXTEND THIS TO THREE #s
};

// example
console.log(Math.GCD([4, 5, 10]));
```

[Demo also in JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/59z28rpk/)

Notice the function in there about the **Least Common Multiple (LCM)**

I am trying to extend this function so that it can compute the LCM of the same two or three user supplied inputs, but I cannot for the life of me get it right. I am a novice at JavaScript and would appreciate any help whatsoever. Note that if a field is left blank it should be omitted from the calculation also, as is done for the GCD.

Comment: @Nina: thank you ever so much! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use these functions:

```
function gcd2(a, b) {
  // Greatest common divisor of 2 integers
  if(!b) return b===0 ? a : NaN;
  return gcd2(b, a%b);
}
function gcd(array) {
  // Greatest common divisor of a list of integers
  var n = 0;
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; ++i)
    n = gcd2(array[i], n);
  return n;
}
function lcm2(a, b) {
  // Least common multiple of 2 integers
  return a*b / gcd2(a, b);
}
function lcm(array) {
  // Least common multiple of a list of integers
  var n = 1;
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; ++i)
    n = lcm2(array[i], n);
  return n;
}
```

Comment: Tried this out and the `lcm2` function seems to return the second input value as opposed to the actual LCM.

Comment: @newbie2015 It works for me, e.g. `lcm2(6,15) === 30`, not `15`.

Comment: I made this fiddle, changing a few variables to correspond to what I had: https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/85/ - perhaps I've implemented something incorrectly.

Comment: Try https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/100/. Or https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/101/, if you want to ignore empty fields.

Comment: You're using `var` statements everywhere, have inadequate spacing, using unbraced `for`s,  and using inline `?` in a way that hurts readability.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you change the structure a little bit for `GCD`and `LCM`, so that both methods have only two arguments.

To get the result of more than two arguments, use [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), which takes two elements from the array and returns a result, which is used as a new insert until the array is finished.

And while the [LCM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_common_multiple) and the [GCD](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greatest_common_divisor) are [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property), you can chain it as desired.

```js
Math.GCD = function twogcd(first, second) {
    if (first < 0) first = -first;
    if (second < 0) second = -second;
    if (second > first) { var temp = first; first = second; second = temp; }
    while (true) {
        first %= second;
        if (first == 0) return second;
        second %= first;
        if (second == 0) return first;
    }
};

Math.LCM = function (first, second) {
    return first * (second / Math.GCD(first, second));
};

document.getElementById('calc').addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    var first = +document.getElementById("first").value,
        second = +document.getElementById("second").value,
        third = +document.getElementById("third").value,
        numbers = [first, second, third],
        resultGCD = numbers.reduce(Math.GCD), // just chain it together
        resultLCM = numbers.reduce(Math.LCM); // just chain it together

    document.getElementById('gcd').innerHTML = resultGCD;
    document.getElementById('lcm').innerHTML = resultLCM;
});
```

```html
GCD: <span id="gcd"></span><br />
LCM: <span id="lcm"></span><br />
<form name="sci-calc" method="POST" id="sci-calc">
    <input type="text" name="stuff[]" class="input-field" id="first" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="stuff[]" class="input-field" id="second" /><br />
    <input type="text" name="stuff[]" class="input-field" id="third" /><br />
    <button type="button" id="calc">CALC</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't figured out what your code is doing but here is the function to find LCM:

```
LCM = function(numbers) {
  console.log(numbers)  
  if (numbers.length < 2) return
  first = numbers[0]
  second = numbers[1]
  var i = j = 1
  var mult1 = first * i++
  var mult2 = second * j++
  while (mult1 != mult2) {
    if (mult1 < mult2)
        mult1 = first * i++
    else
        mult2 = second * j++
  }
  if (numbers.length > 2) {
    numbers[1] = mult1 //I hope you're fine with the fact that 'numbers' gets modified
    mult1 = LCM(numbers.splice(1, numbers.length-1))
  }
    return mult1
}
```

I know It's not efficcient but it illustrates the idea of how to use it with any number of parameters (it's just called recursively).

The fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/grabantot/fr0gzogL/

Comment: I really like this solution, but I'd prefer to stick with the three input fields, so I doctored your fiddle [https://jsfiddle.net/fr0gzogL/17/] but I couldn't get it to accept just two arguments. Is it possible?